# Using a CASE to create an IN statement variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

With the following case statement I need the last When to be stored as 5,6 because I need this variable to be used in a where clause.

Case Statement

```
DECLARE @l_RepAccess as nvarchar(8),@l_RepGroup as varchar(8)

SET @l_RepAccess = 6
SET @l_RepGroup = ''

SELECT @l_RepGroup =
CASE @l_RepAccess 

WHEN '3' THEN 5
WHEN '4' THEN 6
WHEN '6' THEN '5' + ',' + '6' 
ELSE ('')
END  

SELECT @l_RepGroup
```

The variable need to go into this line.

```
or (A.REPORGLVL IN (@l_RepGroup))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Forgot to mention I get the following error message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5,6' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that holds the logic

```
access | group
3      | 5
4      | 6
6      | 5
6      | 6
```

In the where clause

```
Where group in (select group from tbl where access = @l_RepAccess)
```